# For each part below, describe (as precisely as you can) span{v1, v2, v3}.

Tags: linear-algebra

(a) $v_1 = [0 \; 5 \; 10]^T,\; v_2 = [2\; 3\; 0]^T,\; v_3 = [0\; 1\; 0]^T$.

I know what a span is, I just have no idea what exactly this question is asking. So I have three column vectors, sure. But how can I "describe" this span? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about this, start with a smaller number of vectors (say one vector), the span is ALL linear combinations of it (for a single vector all constant multiples). If you were to put them all together over lapping what sort of geometric shape do you get? What about 2 linearly independent vectors?

Comment: @Triatticus Well I can graph a visual representation, is that what you're hinting at?  But I don't think that's what this is asking for. I appreciate the response! I just maybe don't get it.

Comment: This is exactly how I would answer the question, a single vector produces a line, a vector with three components produces a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Two independent vectors span a plane, two vectors with three components span a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @Triatticus after using an online graphing tool, I think you're right! The question I posted kind of makes a pyramid-like shape, the second one is a line (I didn't post that one). Thank you so much!

Comment: Well all three vectors by themselves span a line, any two of them a plane, all three of them span ALL of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Of course you have to check linear independence first